# why the first action/ first route is opened for any url in routing in Zend framework 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have written the following code in bootstrap.php file

```
    protected function _initRoutes() {
     $routers = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
     $adminadd = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:cityadd/', array('module' => 'user', 'controller' => 'city', 'action' => 'add'));
$routers->addRoute('addcity', $adminadd);

     $routing = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
     $adminedit = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/:cityedit/', array('module' => 'user', 'controller' => 'city', 'action' => 'edit'));
$routing->addRoute('edit-city', $adminedit);
    }
```

My project name is `demo`

In my browser when I give the URL `http://localhost/demo/public/cityadd` the page opened is add action page i.e,

```
View script for controller City and script/action name add
```

When I give the URL `http://localhost/demo/public/cityedit` also the page opened is add action page i.e,

```
View script for controller City and script/action name add
```

instead it must be redirected to  `View script for controller City and script/action name edit`

Why the same page is opened or why the page is redirected to same action for any URL given

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using variables in your routes. Variables are preceded with a colon. A route consisting only of a variable will match pretty much anything.

Try writing your routes without the colon:

```
protected function _initRoutes()
{
    $routers = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $adminadd = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/cityadd/', array('module' => 'user', 'controller' => 'city', 'action' => 'add'));
    $routers->addRoute('addcity', $adminadd);

    $routing = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $adminedit = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/cityedit/', array('module' => 'user', 'controller' => 'city', 'action' => 'edit'));
    $routing->addRoute('edit-city', $adminedit);
}
```